# Is there a way to select multiple or all properties of MimeType?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

Im working on a google forms project and I am writing a script so I can move files from one folder to another. I am trying to put files from a source folder in the variable 'files' as you can see in this code I am able to extract JPEG's but it would be very helpful if I were able to use other image file types like png's.

`var files = sourceFolder.getFilesByType(MimeType.JPEG);`

Answer (score 1):

- You want to retrieve the files with the mimeTypes of `image/jpeg` and `image/png`.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

In this answer, I would like to propose to use the method of `searchFiles(params)` in Class DriveApp.

#### Sample script:

From:

```
var files = sourceFolder.getFilesByType(MimeType.JPEG);
```

To:

```
var files = sourceFolder.searchFiles("mimeType='image/jpeg' or mimeType='image/png'");
```

or

```
var files = sourceFolder.searchFiles(`mimeType='${MimeType.JPEG}' or mimeType='${MimeType.PNG}'`);
```

#### Note:

- About `all properties of MimeType`, if you want to retrieve all files except for a small number of mimeType, how about the following sample script? In this script, the files except for the mimeTypes of "image/jpeg", "image/png" are retrieved.

  ```
    var files = sourceFolder.searchFiles("mimeType!='image/jpeg' and mimeType!='image/png'");
  ```

#### References:

- [searchFiles(params)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#searchfilesparams)
- [Search query terms](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/ref-search-terms)